# How to use variable out of the script tag

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, google-places-api, sveltekit

How do I assign the value of my variable `place` to be the value of my variable address? So I can bind the value. They are **NOT** in the same script tag. When I console.log my variable `place` I can see the address, but I have no idea on how to set the value for my variable `address`.

```
<script>
let address = "";
</script>
```

They are **NOT **in the same script tag.

```
<div class="address">
                <label for="">Address: </label> <br />
                <script
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.fsdfsdfcom/maps/api/js?key=s&libraries=places"
                ></script>
                <input
                    id="autocomplete"
                    placeholder="address"
                    type="text"
                    bind:value={address}
                />
                <br />
                <script>
                    let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                        document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
                        {
                            componentRestrictions: { country: "au" },
                        }
                    );

                    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
                        var place = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
```

I want to get my value of my variable `place` in the `addListener` and use the value for the address variable, so I can fetch my data. Everything I tried didn't work. I want to use the value returned from my GoogleAPI, which I can see when I console.log my variable var, to my variable address, which is **NOT** in the same script tag. I tried to use the variable ```address`` with global scope, but it didn't work or I didn't do it correctly. Also I tried to do that, and it didnt work.
[image]

I need to be able to use the variable `place` out of the script tag or anything that allows me to use that to assign its value to address. This is SvelteKit

Att.

**EDIT:**

[image]

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: Is the script tag with `let address` in the same file as your trying to bind the value?

Comment: From what I understood, are you trying to assign the `place` variable value  to the `bind` prop where you get the error?

Comment: @Dolan They are all in the same file. Svelte file.

Comment: @score30 Yes. I don't know how to use the value of ```place``` out of the script tag it is.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access the value of `place` because you create this variable in the `addEventListener()` method. That means the scope of `place` variable is within that function only and you cannot access it anywhere outside of it.

In order to avoid this, you can define the `place` variable outside of the `addEventListener("place_changed", () => {});` and then assign it the value you want. This way, the `place` variable will be in global scope and can be accessed anywhere. Check this:

```
<script>
      let place; // this way PLACE can be accessed any where else
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
          {
              componentRestrictions: { country: "au" },
          }
      );

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
      });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Check my edit and you will see.

Comment: Do you want the value of the input element to be the result of `autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address` ?

Comment: That input element where you have `bind:value` is before the script that the `place` variable is defined, you cannot use it the variable before it starts to exist.

Comment: I thought that would fix as well, But it didnt, check my edit2

Comment: I want the output of the place to be assigned to my address variable. Or anything that allows me to fetch the address I choose on the DB.